# is there a way of showing the user name on another activity after logging in?

Tags: php, android

i have created a register and login page in android studio which work perfectly fine, but now i want when a user logs in, his or her user name is captured and shown in the next activity which is the main activity.

**Here is the login**

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
TextInputEditText textInputEditTextUsername, textInputEditTextPassword;
Button ButtonLogin;
TextView textViewSignUp;
ProgressBar progressBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    textInputEditTextUsername = findViewById(R.id.username);
    textInputEditTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
    ButtonLogin = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    textViewSignUp = findViewById(R.id.signUpText);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);

    textViewSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignUp.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    ButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String username;
            String password;
            TextView number1;


            username = String.valueOf(textInputEditTextUsername.getText());
            password = String.valueOf(textInputEditTextPassword.getText());
            number1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.usernamelog);


            if (!username.equals("") && !password.equals("")) {
                //Start ProgressBar first (Set visibility VISIBLE)
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Starting Write and Read data with URL
                        //Creating array for parameters
                        String[] field = new String[2];
                        field[0] = "username";
                        field[1] = "password";

                        //Creating array for data
                        String[] data = new String[2];
                        data[0] = username;
                        data[1] = password;

                        PutData putData = new 
             PutData("http://192.168.43.88/LoginRegister/login.php", "POST", field, data);
                        if (putData.startPut()) {
                            if (putData.onComplete()) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                String result = putData.getResult();
                                if (result.equals("Login Success")){
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, 
                      MainActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("username","username");
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                                else{
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, 
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //End Write and Read data with URL
                    }
                });
               }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"All fields required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**And the MainActivity.java where i want the user name to be shown.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
NavigationView navigationView;
SliderView sliderView;
    TextView textView;

int[] images = {R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two,
        R.drawable.three,
        R.drawable.four,
        R.drawable.five,
        R.drawable.six};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.usernamelog);
    sliderView = findViewById(R.id.image_slider);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String username = intent.getStringExtra( "username");

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home ");

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setUpToolbar();
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_menu);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId())
            {
                case  R.id.nav_home:

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case  R.id.nav_about:

                    Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class);
                    startActivity(aboutIntent);
                    break;

                case  R.id.nav_contact:

                    Intent contactIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Contact.class);
                    startActivity(contactIntent);
                    break;

                case  R.id.nav_faqs:

                    Intent faqsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FAQs.class);
                    startActivity(faqsIntent);
                    break;


                case  R.id.nav_share:{

                    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    String shareBody =  "http://play.google.com/store/apps/detail?id=" + 
                getPackageName();
                    String shareSub = "Try now";
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSub);
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));

                }
                break;

                case R.id.log:{
                    Intent logIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(logIntent);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    CardView mainButton = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.StartUp);
    CardView mainButton1 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.siting);
    CardView mainButton2 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.farmplan);
    CardView mainButton3 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cagedesign);
    CardView mainButton4 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.production);
    CardView mainButton5 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.marketing);
    CardView mainButton6 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.start);
    ImageButton mainButton7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.log);
    TextView number1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usernamelog);


    mainButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mainButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Siting.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mainButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Farmplan.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mainButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CageDesign.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mainButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Production2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mainButton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Marketing.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mainButton6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



    SliderAdapter sliderAdapter = new SliderAdapter(images);

    sliderView.setSliderAdapter(sliderAdapter);
    sliderView.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimationType.WORM);
    sliderView.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.DEPTHTRANSFORMATION);
    sliderView.startAutoCycle();

}
```

please help me so that i can upload my app on play store. Thank you very much

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

From the php server return the desired username as part of the response.
In this case you should modify your **results** variable type, from string to a JSON object.
In the Login Activity pass it as an intent extra, something like this

```
intent.putExtra("username",usernameResponse);
```

Here, **usernameResponse** is a variable that holds the preferred username returned from the php server.

Showing the php code could help a lot more!

Comment: Here is the php code you requested @Vincent<?php
require "DataBase.php";
$db = new DataBase();
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if ($db->dbConnect()) {
        if ($db->logIn("users", $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
            echo "Login Success";
        } else echo "Username or Password wrong";
    } else echo "Error: Database connection";
} else echo "All fields are required";
?>

Comment: in the echo statements, instead of returning a bare string, return a json like: {"code": "login success", "username": $_POST['username']}. then in the login activity parse this as json to get the username and pass it to the aforementioned username variable

Comment: i have not got you

Comment: i think you should read on json(and web API) and android sharedpreferences, mostly the later. i believe they will help